# How to use the predict function after correcting for oversampling by an offset argument

Tags: r

I have an oversampled data set with 2336 observations and about 30% event rate where the original event rate is about 2.9%. My `glm` model looks like this:

```
Churn_Prediction <- glm(formula=DummyGB~.,
   data=OverSampleDev, family=binomial,offset = rep(2.7,nrow(OverSampleDev)))
```

where the offset argument is used to correct for the oversampling and the value 2.7 is derived as : `ln⁡(((r1*(1-p1 ))/(p1*(1-r1 ) ))`, where p1 and r1 are the original event rate and the boosted event rate respectively.

The problem is that when I want to validate the model with the predict function applied to another data set with number of rows differing from those of the "OverSampleDev" data set, I receive an error message and a warning:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Prediction", value = c(0.147198536202437,  : 
  replacement has 2336 rows, data has 583
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In offset + eval(object$call$offset, newdata) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In predictor + offset :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Should I create new regression model with an offset argument compatible with the dimension of the data set to which I intend to apply it or should I change my procedure of oversampling correction to make the model more applicable?